# Need to understand transaction.factory_class of Hibernate configuration

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

In my hibernate.cfg.xml file, one of the properties is -

```
<property name = "transaction.factory_class"> <!--1-->
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory <!--2-->
</property> <!--3-->
```

Other properties are easy to understand. But, many questions came to my mind when I saw the above property.

**line 1 -** this specifies the class implementing the Transaction**Factory** interface.

**Q1 -** I saw the java docs for TransactionFactory but did not understand what it really is. What does this "Factory" mean ? Why don't they call it TransactionGenerator as per the line -

> Contract for generating Hibernate Transaction instances.

**Q2 -** TransactionFactory lead me to Transaction. Is this exactly the same as a Database transaction ?

**Q3 -**

> A single session might span multiple transactions since the notion of
>   a session (a conversation between the application and the datastore)
>   is of coarser granularity than the notion of a transaction. However,
>   it is intended that there be at most one uncommitted Transaction
>   associated with a particular Session at any time.

*...the notion of a session is of coarser granularity than the notion of a transaction.*

What does that mean in simple words ?

--

> However, it is intended that there be at most one uncommitted
>   Transaction associated with a particular Session at any time.

Why do you intend this ?

I don't think that the API docs are clear. Makes a n00b life miserable.

Answer (score 9):

**Q1** - The reasoning is clear. The transaction creation follows a factory pattern. For example, in an environment where application servers (like JBOSS, WebSphere etc) manage the transaction creation via JTA APIs, you will use a JTA Transaction factory to create transactions and that transactions will be further used by hibernate. In a purely Spring managed environment, Spring can be configured to use a HibernateTransactionFactory. In short, it would follow a similar fashion as:

```
IFactory f= FactoryCreatorForYourEnvironment.create();
Transaction t = f.create();
```

**Q2 and Q3** - Yes, a hibernate transaction factory creates database transactions on underlying DB. Note that a session may be spanning over multiple transactions - A hibernate session abstracts a database connection. Over the same connection, multiple begin transaction, commit transaction cycles are possible. Example: REQUIRE_NEW properties if the participating beans (EJBs, or SPRING beans). So session is a broader (coarser) term as mentioned in the documentation.

Transactions are required for any writes, deletes, protected reads. So the session holds an implicit transaction. You can read a related stack overflow article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085095/should-i-be-using-sql-transactions-while-reading-records).

HTH.